# Do you need to create reverse zones for every ordinary zone in BIND DNS?

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I'm trying to create a DNS server at home, but it's not working properly.

Here is my `named.conf.local` file:

```
zone "news.home" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.home-news";
};

zone "chat.home" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.home-chat";
};

zone "iot.home" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.home-iot";
};

zone "**1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.192";
};
```

When I run `nslookup news.home` from my other machine (with DNS set to my DNS server) it shows

```
Server UnKnown
Address: 192.168.1.100

Name: news.home
Address: 192.168.1.100
```

This seems to indicate that it is working. Yet when I do `ping news.home` I get

```
Ping request could not find host news.home. PLease check the name and try against.
```

I'm wondering if perhaps I failed to do something in the reverse zone department.

**For reference, here is `zones/db.home-news`:**

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     bugstein-server.news.home. admin.news.home. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
news.home.    IN NS   bugstein-server.news.home.
news.home.    IN A    192.168.1.100
;@      IN      NS      localhost.
;@      IN      A       127.0.0.1
;@      IN      AAAA    ::1
bugstein-server        IN A    192.168.1.100
home            IN A    192.168.1.100
gateway         IN A    192.168.1.1
```

And here is `zones/db.192`:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     bugstein-server.root.home. admin.root.home. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      bugstein-server.
1       IN      PTR     gateway.root.home.
5       IN      PTR     bugstein-server.root.home.
;@1.0.0 IN      PTR     localhost.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ability to do forward resolution (eg `nslookup news.home` or `ping news.home`) is not affected by whether or not you have a reverse zone.  You don't need a reverse zone for forward lookup, and you generally don't need one at all except in specific cases that you may already be aware of (it can help mail delivery if you are running your own internet-facing mail host, which you probably aren't).  So I would advise not worrying about reverse zones.  In particular, you're only really setting up "fake" reverse zones anyway, as they are not resolvable by the wider internet and don't reflect real IP address ownership.

Now, it looks like your other machine is using Windows, correct?  There may be a quirk on that ping where it is not doing a DNS lookup for that hostname.  You could try forcing a DNS lookup by adding a dot to the end of the name as in:

```
ping news.home.
```

If that does solve the problem, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330395/dns-problem-nslookup-works-ping-doesnt) for more info.

If it doesn't, sorry I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`home` may conflict with mDNS (Multicast DNS) which uses this domain.  Try using a different domain such as `localnet`.

You generally don't need to configure reverse zones for IPv4.  Other than SMTP MX servers few applications will expect them to be configured.

If you aren't using addresses from one of the private network blocks, it is unlikely you will be able to configure entries that are usable off your local network.  Reverse zones need to be configured by the IP provider.

On a local networks you may want your DHCP server to be able to update the DNS to reflect IPs that have been served.  This is difficult with `bind`, but can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse zone is not mandatory but recommended. Some application like SSH try to do a reverse lookup at the login.

Regarding your ping issue, you may have to add a search entry in your resolv.conf on your client (you may update your dhcp server in order to push this setting to all network devices).

```
search news.home
nameserver 192.168.1.100
```

Then try to ping your home server

```
ping home
```

For some reason, the FQDN (home.news.home) is not working when a graphic interface is installed, because the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is altered by [NOTFOUND=return], not sure about the exact reason.